# How the only class col-xs-12 works in large screen in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Talking about grid system of bootstrap 3. If we use `col-xs-12` class in our code it will also works for big screen along with small screen, though not necessary to use `col-sm-12` or `col-md-12` or `col-lg-12` class.

From the below image, it is clearly saying extra small size devices which is `col-xs-12` are used for **<768px**. Then how can it works for large screen when we use `col-xs-12` only ?

[image]

From coding, this below codes will also work for large screen also though I used only `class="col-xs-12"`, did not use  `class="col-sm-12"` or  `class="col-md-12"` or  `class="col-lg-12"`

```
<div class="container">        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">ABC</div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is located into the `bootstrap.css` file.
If you try to search for `col-xs-12` you will notice that the width is set to `100%`, so this means that using only the class `col-xs-12` the div will be rendered at 100% of the width, according of where it is content.

So if you know that a specific div will be full width on all responsive views, instead to write lot of code, you can only call out the `col-xs-12`, keeping your code clean and simple.